# Converting from .WAV to .txt or .dat with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to convert from .WAV to ASCII text file for utilizing in my script. FFMpeg can translate from .wav to .raw:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le output.raw
```

but I can't translate from .raw to .txt or .dat.
I know of hexdump but I need something that works in windows.

Any suggestions on how to make this work, or another method all together of converting from .wav to .txt?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1481748

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is a tool to encode and decode audio and video between various compression formats vs. the raw audio and video data, and encapsulate or extract various streams of those from various container formats.  It does not have any feature to interpret the meaning of the data such as recognizing words in audio or shapes in video.  (though you can probably extract the text of subtitles from a video)

Interpreting human speech is a "hard problem" and is still an active research topic for many companies and universities.  Languages and dialects (and the constant evolution of new words) make this especially difficult.

If you want something free that you can run in a script without reaching out to an Internet service, you need to look at software like [CMU Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/), [Julius](http://julius.osdn.jp/en_index.php) or [Kaldi](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi)

I have tried Sphinx and Juluis, with mixed results.  It was a while back so I would suggest trying the latest version of all 3 and see which gives you the best performance for the particular audio you are working with.

Comment: Excellent and valid answer, but I am simply looking to convert the data points in my signal to a list of ASCII values. ie: in a sin wave sampled at 48kHz, I would like to know all those values in a list.

Comment: Heh, ok.  Can you update the question to better-describe this format you're looking for?  I've never heard of people processing audio as text numbers.  If I wanted to do something like convert a WAV file to an array of integers in a C program I would just load the .raw into memory and then type cast it as int16_t.  If I wanted to load into a text-based scripting language like perl I would ``unpack "s*", $raw_buffer``.  In fact if you have perl on windows, it's an easy 1-liner.

Comment: For that matter, if hexdump is all you want you could install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)